# Enable Standard Library optimization in debug mode with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, optimization, c++17, visual-studio-debugging, standard-library

When I run my program with Visual Studio in debug mode I get a real slow down compared to release mode. I know that debug mode unoptimize code and especialy the one from Standard Library which I don't care about. However I really need to be able to debug an unoptimize code when I wrote it. Is there any way to keep Visual in debug mode with my code fully unoptimized while everything from the Standard Library is optimized ?
Cheers
Victor

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you could change the project property for you project or referenced project like optimization or un-optimize if you have the project source code or you can re-compile it. Of course, if we enable the optimization for one project or reference project, it would impact some debugging feature more or less:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/606cbtzs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396